# Regular Expression to parse 112^3^1^1^

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to parse a string like `112^3^1^1^` into separate values.

The first ('112') is order_no, second one is line_no, third one is release_no, and the fourth one is receipt_no.

What kind of regex can I use in Oracle?

Comment: There are various regex functions such as regexp_instr, regex_substr, regexp_count, regexp_replace. What output do you need to see from this example? Do you mean PL/SQL (the programming language) specifically, or Oracle SQL?

Comment: I am going to take one of this values to use in a Function which will be a column in my SQL View. example: abcd_api.get_unit_meas(order_no,line_no,release_no,receipt_no) . what is differance of PLSQL and Oracle SQL?

Comment: PL/SQL is the in-database programming language for writing procedures, functions, sudoku solvers etc. SQL is SQL (though we can say 'Oracle SQL' to make it clear we mean Oracle's version rather than Microsoft's etc). I think with some other vendors the line is somewhat blurred and a procedure tends to be some kind of a stored script with some extra features in it. Not so in Oracle.

Comment: its ok, thanks :) but still i dont know how to get this values. I am researching regexp functions but i could not understand or found solution for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with demo (str) as
     ( select '112^3^1^1^' from dual )
select str
     , regexp_substr(str,'[^^]+',1,1) as order_no
     , regexp_substr(str,'[^^]+',1,2) as line_no
     , regexp_substr(str,'[^^]+',1,3) as release_no
     , regexp_substr(str,'[^^]+',1,4) as receipt_no
from   demo;

STR        ORDER_NO   LINE_NO   RELEASE_NO   RECEIPT_NO
---------- ---------- --------- ------------ ----------
112^3^1^1^ 112        3         1            1
```

This depends on each component having a value, because the pattern it is using is *'one or more characters that are not `^`'*. It would need a bit of tweaking if a value was missing, e.g. `'112^3^^1^'` (no release_no).

Comment: Thank you very much William :) this is what i wish to find :)